# Pagefactory init elements function to be declared once in code for code optimization

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, page-factory

I am automating my project using page object model. But I noticed that whenever I am writing two different scenarios to be automated for same page object, I need to initialize elements for that test case each time I write the test case using Pagefactory.initElements method. Is there any way so that this can be initialized only once and can be reused in all test cases ?

I tried to make reference variable i.e. for e.g. "manorgpom ort=PageFactory.initElements(getdriver(), manorgpom.class);" ort to be static but it is giving null pointer exception. I initialized them outside my test cases and made the reference variable static but to no success.

```
    @Test(priority=3)
public void orgact() throws Exception {
    manorgpom ort=PageFactory.initElements(getdriver(), manorgpom.class);
    getdriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ort.actorg();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}

@Test(priority=4)
public void orgadd() throws Exception{
    manorgpom ort=PageFactory.initElements(getdriver(), manorgpom.class);
    getdriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    ort.addorg();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

If you see above I need to initialize web elements each time I write test case. Each time I need to mention "manorgpom ort=PageFactory.initElements(getdriver(), manorgpom.class);". I want to optimize this.

This is the manageorgpom class snippet.

```
    public class manorgpom extends Basetest{
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@href='/organization']")
WebElement orglink;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='anticon anticon-filter']")
WebElement filter;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@placeholder='e.g. High School USA']")
WebElement filternametxt;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[text()='Activate']")
WebElement activatelink;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@placeholder='e.g. Johnny']")
WebElement contactfirstname;
```

When I made the ort reference variable static, I am getting java.lang.nullPointerException each time I run the suite. Please help me.

Comment: Adding PageFactory.initElements in page class constructor might help. Can you give more details?

Comment: Exactly what you need ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Did you try initializing elements and Page object level? Can you share your page object class details

Comment: I have added the snippet where I declared all the web elements.

Comment: Does your getdriver() creates new driver object everytime?

Comment: No. I have declared it private and I wrote getdriver() method to access that web driver reference variable. What I did is," private WebDriver driver; protected WebDriver getdriver(){return driver;};" in a Base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your webDriver is geting instantiated everytime. You need to make it singleton and use only one instance of the webDriver.

```
public class driverSingleton { 
private static final webDriver instance = new ChromeDriver();   //just for example 
//private constructor to avoid client applications to use constructor private EagerInitializedSingleton(){} 
public static driverSingleton getInstance(){ return instance;

}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add some code to better show what you mean?

Comment: public class driverSingleton {
     
    private static final webDriver instance = new ChromeDriver(); //just for example
     
    //private constructor to avoid client applications to use constructor
    private EagerInitializedSingleton(){}
 
    public static driverSingleton getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}

Comment: Now use getInstance to get the driver instance and work with it. This should solve your problem

Comment: Please do not put code in comments, but instead edit your answer to enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

** try this code it will definitely help you

public class manorgpom extends Basetest{

```
private final Config config;
```

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@href='/organization']")
WebElement orglink;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='anticon anticon-filter']")
WebElement filter;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@placeholder='e.g. High School USA']")
WebElement filternametxt;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[text()='Activate']")
WebElement activatelink;

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@placeholder='e.g. Johnny']")
WebElement contactfirstname;

```
protected manorgpom(WebDriver driver, Config config, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(driver);

    this.config = config;

    if (autoInitialize) {
        PageFactory.initElements(getWebDriver(), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).